# Error at Student a=new Student();

Tags: java

I am getting error as following :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> No enclosing instance of type New is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type New (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of New).
>   at n.New.main(New.java:7)

Following is my code :

```
package n;

public class New 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Student a=new Student();
        a.name="abc";
        a.number=6;
        a.marks=1;

        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(a.number);
        System.out.println(a.marks);
    }

    class Student
    {
        String name;
        int number;
        int marks;

    }

}
```

Comment: @SantoshReddy Did you actually *read* the error message?

Comment: @magic-sudo both comments are wrong, don´t need to be done actually, and aren´t the fault for the compilation error

Comment: what is that about.actually i am a beginner .could you tell me the changes?

Comment: i would place classes like Student in a new class file. makes them easier to access and doesnt bring up such errors

Comment: You need to add the `static` keyword like this: `static class Student`

Answer (score 2):

Your class Student is not static and you are trying to access it from static context which is not allowed.

Your code should be as follows:

```
package n;

public class New {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student();
        a.name = "abc";
        a.number = 6;
        a.marks = 1;

        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(a.number);
        System.out.println(a.marks);
    }

    static class Student {
        String name;
        int number;
        int marks;

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @chirag parmar. i got it.

Comment: @SantoshReddy Generally it is not good practice to make static class. Either you access inner class with reference of outer class.. Do you really need a inner class?

Comment: Ya ...I agree with @iMBMT..

Comment: Just a quick heads-up: Don't edit phrases like "EDIT:" into questions/answers that you edit. It's considered as noise.

Comment: Ohk...@Seth ..I will take care..:) Thanks ..!!

Answer (score 1):

The class `Student` is a non-static inner class of the class `New`, and must be accessed from an object of the class `New`. It cannot be accessed directly from `main` as `main` is static and `Student` is not. As a solution, just declare it outside `New` like this:

```
package n;

public class New {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student();
        a.name = "abc";
        a.number = 6;
        a.marks = 1;

        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(a.number);
        System.out.println(a.marks);
    }
}

class Student {
    String name;
    int number;
    int marks;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error happens because `Student` is an inner class of `New`.

As `Student` is defined as `class Student`, it can only exist inside of an instance of `New`. So there are a few ways to solve this "problem".

The most simple one: make it

```
static class Student
```

Due to this, a single instance of `Student` isn´t bound to exist in an instance of `New`.

Another one is creating an instance of `New` where you create an instance of `Student`:

```
Student a = new New().new Student();
```

But for the purpose of starting to learn how to program, I'd say: remove the inner `Student` class and start with `Student` being the outer class.

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int number;
    int marks;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a = new Student();
        a.name = "abc";
        a.number = 6;
        a.marks = 1;

        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(a.number);
        System.out.println(a.marks);
    }
}
```

Some additions for the starter:

include a constructor in `Student` as `Student(String, int, int)` and call it when initializing a new instance of `Student`, instead of initializing it and setting the variables afterward:

```
new Student("abc", 1, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You inner class should be static as you are trying to access it from static context which gives error.

```
static class Student {
        String name;
        int number;
        int marks;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. make the Student class static
2. initialize the outer class first and then initialize the inner class like this:

   New n = new New();
   Student a=n.new Student();

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html for more details.